# CopyFromRecordset copies & pastes only first one row even though multiple records are present in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, adodb

I have an Excel sheet containing table like data

```
strSQL = "SELECT S.FIELD_NAME1,S.FIELD_NAME2,S.FIELD_NAME3 from [SourceData$A1:IV6] S"

Dim cn as ADODB.Connection
Dim rs as ADODB.Recordset
cn.Open strCon
Set rs = CmdSqlData.Execute()
Worksheets("SourceData").Cells.ClearContent
Worksheets("AnswerData").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
```

**Results :**
Only first row and other records are ignored.

I have tried below query .,

```
strSQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) from [SourceData$A1:IV6] S"
```

Which gives `5` as result.

Please let me know why other records not copied into recordset?

Comment: That SQL only returns a single number. You probably meant `SELECT * FROM` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a subroutine that successfully pastes a recordset.

Note that the range it pastes to is the same size of the recordset via the intMaxRow and intMaxCol variables:

```
Sub sCopyFromRS()
'Send records to the first
'sheet in a new workbook
'
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim intMaxCol As Integer
Dim intMaxRow As Integer
Dim objXL As Excel.Application
Dim objWkb As Workbook
Dim objSht As Worksheet
  Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Customers", _
                    dbOpenSnapshot)
  intMaxCol = rs.Fields.Count
  If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    rs.MoveLast:    rs.MoveFirst
    intMaxRow = rs.RecordCount
    Set objXL = New Excel.Application
    With objXL
      .Visible = True
      Set objWkb = .Workbooks.Add
      Set objSht = objWkb.Worksheets(1)
      With objSht
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(intMaxRow, _
            intMaxCol)).CopyFromRecordset rs
      End With
    End With
  End If
End Sub
```

Using that example as a model, I'd try somehting like this for your code:

```
strSQL = "SELECT S.FIELD_NAME1,S.FIELD_NAME2,S.FIELD_NAME3 from [SourceData$A1:IV6] S"

Dim cn as ADODB.Connection
Dim rs as ADODB.Recordset
Dim intMaxCol as Integer
Dim intMaxRow as Integer

cn.Open strCon
Set rs = CmdSqlData.Execute()
intMaxCol = rs.Fields.Count
'- MoveLast/First to get an accurate RecordCount
rs.MoveLast 
rs.MoveFirst

If rs.RecordCount > 0 then
    '-thought you could put the MoveLast/First here but maybe not.
    intMaxRow = rs.RecordCount
    With Worksheets("AnswerData")
        .Range(.Cells(2,1),.Cells(intMaxRow+1,intMaxColumn)).CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With
End If
```

Comment: will rs.RecordCount give total number of records present in recordset ? in my case i am getting the result as -1 even though i have 5 records in a recordset

Comment: rs.Recordcount returns the correct number of records after you movelast and movefirst
This is required for it to parse through and count them.
 I've edited the code to put the rs.MoveLast rs.MoveFirst before the if statement because I don't remember off the top of my head if you can get away with putting it inside the IF or not (i thought you could) )

Comment: Thanks Logan - unfortunately I didn't read the comments before I tried to figure out what was going wrong - it ALWAYS skips over the IF statement as it returns a -1 - apparently this means there ARE records, so maybe the If statement should be if rs.RecordCount = -1 (still wrong in the first example). Thanks for the rest tho Gimp - otherwise very useful. ;)

Answer (score 2):

This answer depends upon your ODBC database driver available in Excel.

Due to my corp env, I am forced to use a very old Oracle ODBC driver.  In my case, `Recordset.RecordCount` is always `-1`.  By default, `Recordset.MoveLast` and `Recordset.MoveFirst` is not supported.  Like the original question, calls to `Excel.Range.CopyFromRecordset(Recordset)` also only write a single row.

You may need to configure your `ADODB.Recordset` differently.  Try this code:

```
Dim dbConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim rng As Excel.Range
Dim rowCount As Long

' TODO: Init your dbConn here.
' TODO: Init your rng here.

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
' http://www.w3schools.com/ado/prop_rs_cursortype.asp
rs.CursorType = ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenKeyset
rs.Open sql, dbConn
rowCount = rng.CopyFromRecordset(rs)
```

For my driver, this fixes the issue.  However, your mileage may vary.

[You can read more about ADO cursor types here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677593%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same problem.

Only Replace

```
set rst = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE;")
```

with

```
call rst.open("SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE;", conn)
```

Then the problem is sovled

But， I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Copy actual record:

```
Worksheets("AnswerData").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs, 1
```

Copy next five records:

```
Worksheets("AnswerData").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs, 5
```

Copy 3 fields from actual record and so...

```
Worksheets("AnswerData").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs, 1, 3
```