# Run SQL Query on SQL Server 2008 and Copy Results to an Excel Spreadsheet From VBA Macro

Tags: sql-server-2008, excel, vba

How do I write a VBA macro to run a SQL query on a MS SQL Server 2008 Database, and have it output the results into a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Excel and then the Macro Editor (Alt + F11)
2. Go to Tools> References and add the latest installed version of Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects X.X Library (in my case 6.1)
3. Add a new Sub as follows

```
Sub RunSQL(sConnectionString, sSqlQuery, sWorkSheet, nStartColumn, nStartRow)

    Dim oConnection As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim oRecordSet As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sQuery As String
    Dim intMaxCol As Integer
    Dim intMaxRow As Integer

    'Connection to SQL Server
    Call oConnection.Open(sConnectionString)

    ' Get Recordset
    Call oRecordSet.Open(sSqlQuery, oConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly)

    ' Get SQL Query Column Count
    intMaxCol = oRecordSet.Fields.Count
    If oRecordSet.RecordCount > 0 Then

        ' Get SQL Query Row Count
        intMaxRow = oRecordSet.RecordCount

        ' Paste data into sheet
        Call Worksheets(sWorkSheet).Range(Worksheets(sWorkSheet).Cells(nStartRow, nStartColumn), Worksheets(sWorkSheet).Cells(intMaxRow + nStartRow, intMaxCol + nStartColumn)).CopyFromRecordset (oRecordSet)

    End If

    ' Close objects
    oRecordSet.Close
    oConnection.Close
End Sub
```

4. Call this from your code, updating the parameters as follows:

```
Call RunSQL("Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=[[SERVER]]\[[INSTANCE]];Database=[[DATABASE]];Trusted_Connection=Yes;", _
         "SELECT TOP 1 CAST(UniqueId AS VARCHAR(40)), Name FROM Employee WITH (NOLOCK)", _
         "Sheet1", _
         2, _
         3)
```

In case it helps, I got this from a winding route involving the following posts:

- http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-10-0-oledb-provider/
- http://www.w3schools.com/ado/prop_rs_cursortype.asp
- http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=163196
- [CopyFromRecordset copies & pastes only first one row even though multiple records are present in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426103/copyfromrecordset-copies-pastes-only-first-one-row-even-though-multiple-record)